# Access cell link value in target dashboard

Tags: grafana

Just started using Grafana today and trying render a table value as a link so that I can pass a cell value to a new dashboard using ${__cell}

So I've setup the link to my new dashboard like this:

https://*****.grafana.net/d/pUiq6LSZz/pre-prod-pod-dashboard?orgId=1&podName=${__cell}

What I can't figure out is how to get the value of the podName query string I'm passing so that I can base queries in the target dashboard on this value.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer which in the end was very simple. For anyone who's interested...

1. Create a variable of type constant in the dashboard in which the value will be consumed
2. When passing the value as a query string from the current dashboard, the variable name must be prefixed with "var-". So for the example in the original post with a variable name podName, the URL would be...

https://*****.grafana.net/d/pUiq6LSZz/pre-prod-pod-dashboard?orgId=1&`var-`podName=${__cell}